# APPLICATION FAILED TO START following method did not exist:org.springframework.plugin.core.PluginRegistry.of(org.springframework.plugin.core.Plugin[])

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, build

I have newly created a spring boot project and added swagger dependencies, now while I am trying to run my application I am getting below error, I have tried this solution
[Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66930313/orrect-the-classpath-of-your-application-so-that-it-contains-a-single-compatibl) and this [Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62540189/correct-the-classpath-of-your-application-so-that-it-contains-a-single-compatib?rq=1) from stackoverflow but it did not solved my issue.
Kindly help me out here.

Here is the rror Description:

```html
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

    org.springframework.hateoas.server.core.DelegatingLinkRelationProvider.<init>(DelegatingLinkRelationProvider.java:36)

The following method did not exist:

    'org.springframework.plugin.core.PluginRegistry org.springframework.plugin.core.PluginRegistry.of(org.springframework.plugin.core.Plugin[])'

The method's class, org.springframework.plugin.core.PluginRegistry, is available from the following locations:

    jar:file:/C:/Users/john/.m2/repository/org/springframework/plugin/spring-plugin-core/1.2.0.RELEASE/spring-plugin-core-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/org/springframework/plugin/core/PluginRegistry.class

The class hierarchy was loaded from the following locations:

    org.springframework.plugin.core.PluginRegistry: file:/C:/Users/john/.m2/repository/org/springframework/plugin/spring-plugin-core/1.2.0.RELEASE/spring-plugin-core-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar


Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of org.springframework.plugin.core.PluginRegistry
```

pom.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.pavan</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-ecommerce</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>spring-boot-ecommerce</name>
    <description>Spring Boot Ecommerce Project</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Used for configuring Swagger API -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

SwaggerConfig.java

```html
package com.john.ecommerce.configuration;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport;

import springfox.documentation.builders.RequestHandlerSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.spi.DocumentationType;
import springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.Docket;
import springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations.EnableSwagger2;



@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport{
    
    
        @Bean
        public Docket productApi() {
            return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                    .select().apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.john.ecommerce"))
                    .build();
        }
        
        @Override
        protected void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
            registry.addResourceHandler("swagger-ui.html")
                    .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");

            registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**")
                    .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
        }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that you have incompatible versions. Please try the following (replace `springfox-swagger2` and `springfox-swagger-ui` dependencies with `springfox-boot-starter`):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.pavan</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-ecommerce</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>spring-boot-ecommerce</name>
    <description>Spring Boot Ecommerce Project</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Used for configuring Swagger API -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Thank You! Dias, It did resolved my build issue, but my swagger it not turning up. For the reference i have attached the swagger class file, do i need to modify anything in swagger if i change it to starter pom.

Comment: Try removing the `@EnableSwagger2` annotation and `.paths(PathSelectors.any())` before `.build();` in the `Docket` configuration. Please check the migration information at https://github.com/springfox/springfox#migrating-from-earlier-snapshot.

Comment: Thanks Dias, my build issue is resolved with the dependencies and looked into web to configure swagger with starter pom. It is working now.